# I have both OCI (Overseas Citizen of India) and Indian visa. How do I cancel Indian visa and retain OCI?

Tags: visas, india

I am a US citizen (US Passport holder) and I have a Overseas Citizen of India card. I have an Indian visa in my US passport as well. I traveled to India, and was almost stopped by Immigration for having both. They let me through but warned that I needed to cancel the visa. They did not specify how.

This is how I ended up with both:

1. Applied for OCI. It was taking a while and putting travel in jeopardy.
2. Applied for Indian visa.
3. Received Indian visa.
4. Received OCI.

How do I cancel my Indian Visa while retaining my OCI?

Comment: Were either, or both, issued through an embassy or consulate and, if so, have you contacted either/both?